# discord.py command not responding

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

bot = Bot(command_prefix = ".")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    if message.author == bot.user:
       return
    
    if message.content.startswith("hello"):
        await message.channel.send('hello!')



@bot.command(name="lol")
async def _lol(ctx):
    print("lelele")
    print(ctx.author)
    await ctx.send("lelele")
```

- when I'm typing .lol, Bot is not responding
- if I type "hello", the bot answers
- where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the default provided `on_message` forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your `on_message`.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

bot = Bot(command_prefix=".")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("hello"):
        await message.channel.send('hello!')
        
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command(name="lol")
async def _lol(ctx):
    print("lelele")
    print(ctx.author)
    await ctx.send("lelele")
```

[Why does on_message make my commands stop working?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)